# How to create cyrillic input on windows phone?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

On my `Nexus 7` input keyboard I have an option to switch languages (`Bulgarian`, `Russian` and `English`).

I want to create such input on windows phone application, but was not able to find a way to do that?

I am not going to deploy the application on the store, just wanted to enabled this on the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users can set this for themselves in the keyboard settings. You can't interact with the keyboard as a developer aside from setting it's inputscope (eg. web address, e-mail, numbers).